# Folder Tree with NTFS Permissions

Tags: powershell, tree, treeview, ntfs

I'm trying to build a little script with PowerShell, but I'm stuck.

I need to give out the structure of a folder as a tree with its NTFS permissions.

```
C:\TEST
├───Test1 - Access
│   ├───Test1.1 - Access
│   └───Test1.2 - Access
│       └───Test1.2.1 - Access
├───Test2 - Access
│   ├───Test2.1 - Access
│   └───Test2.2 - Access
├───Test3 - Access
└───Test4 - Access
    ├───Test4.1 - Access
    ├───Test4.2 - Access
    └───Test4.3 - Access
```

Something like this.

I tried with `Get-ChidlItem C:\Test -Recurse` and `Get-Acl`, but I couldn't figure out how to display the results as a tree.

Comment: The `tree` utility doesn't allow for listing permissions. There are a number of approaches that will provide you with a list view ([see here](https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/need-script-to-list-folder-permissions-in-folder-tree-1/)), but if you must have a tree view you'll probably need to write it yourself. I wrote [something similar in VBScript](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/auditacls.shtml) a couple years ago, but doing it in PowerShell should be a lot simpler than that.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I might work on it if I have time. Basically, you'd want two functions that act recursively. One would convert GCI output to a standard ps object structure with noteproperties defining the structure. The next would actually write the output of the first function out to a tree-view. I thought maybe something similar would exist online, but no luck.

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Tree/1.0.0/Content/Show-Tree.ps1 This may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a script that I wrote recently to output a directory structure as a tree with file sizes to the console.

You can easily modify the `Write-Host` lines to remove the file sizes and add in your ACL information (I'm not really sure aesthetically how this will work).

The big limitation of using `Write-Host` is that you can't work with the data further down the script, you can't output the data to a file - `Start-Transcript` loses the formatting.

Jacob Colvin's comments descript a much better approach, something I would be interested to see in practice.

The only other approach I could think of, would be to create an object which combines the `Get-ACL` and `Get-ChildItem` data, and then when outputting the data, counting the `\`'s in the directory structure to generate the indentation.

```
function Show-Tree
{
    param
    (
        $directory
    )
    if ((Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command -eq 'Show-Tree') {
        Write-host "├──" -NoNewline
        if(Test-Path $directory/*)
        {
            Write-host "┬" -NoNewline
        }
        else
        {
            Write-host "─" -NoNewline
        }
        Write-Host "$($directory | Split-Path -Leaf)/"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$directory"
        $Script:StartingIndent = ($directory).Split("\").Count+1
    }
    Get-ChildItem -path $directory -File | % { 
        $i = 0
        $indent = ($_.FullName).Split("\").Count-$script:StartingIndent
        while($i -lt $indent)
        {
            [console]::Write("│  ")
            $i++
        }
        if(($_.length / 1MB) -ge 1)
        {
            Write-Host "├───[$([int]($_.length / 1MB)) MB] $($_.name)"
        }
        elseif(($_.length / 1KB -ge 1))
        {
            Write-Host "├───[$([int]($_.length / 1KB)) KB] $($_.name)"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "├───[$($_.length) B] $($_.name)"
        }
    }
    Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Directory | % {
        $i = 0
        $indent = ($_.FullName).Split("\").Count-$script:StartingIndent
        while($i -lt $indent)
        {
            Write-host "│  " -NoNewline
            $i++
        }
        Show-Tree -directory $_.FullName
    }
}

Show-Tree -directory C:\Testing
```

Output

```
C:\Testing
├───[7 KB] $RY3NETI.prop
├───[9 KB] Book1.xlsx
├───[308 B] csvOut.csv
├───[308 B] csvOut2.csv
├───[297 B] csvout3.csv
├───[6 MB] Shakespear.txt
├───[570 KB] ShakeSpeareUniqueWords.txt
├───[1 KB] Transcript.txt
├──┬Test1/
│  ├───[183 B] filename.rtf
│  ├───[7 KB] img3.png
│  ├───[18 KB] img4.png
│  ├───[43 KB] img5.png
│  ├───[19 KB] img7.png
│  ├───[26 KB] test.doc
├──┬Test2/
│  ├───[83 MB] filetest.rar
│  ├───[7 KB] img10.png
│  ├───[18 KB] img9.png
│  ├──┬Test2 Subfolder/
│  │  ├───[33 KB] img1.png
│  │  ├───[17 KB] img2.png
│  │  ├───[14 KB] img8.png
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself curious about this problem and started working on something. There are a number of issues but I wanted to post the "general idea".

Start by getting FullNames and appending the ACL info to the file name:

```
$x = (Get-ChildItem C:\Users\j309921\Desktop\ -Recurse).FullName | ForEach-Object {
  "$_ - $((Get-Acl -Path $_).Access.AccessControlType | Select-Object -Unique)"
}
```

For some reason I found that GCI doesn't always return all the paths. I've not looked into this behavior yet. Anyway...

Next I made this function to separate the paths out and put them into objects. I think this could be replaced for speed, but it makes things easier to work with in the next parts.

```
function Convert-GCItoObject {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage='Items to process')]$InputObject
  )
  process {
    $output = @()
    $InputObject -split '\\' | ForEach-Object{ $output += $_ }
    for($i=$output.Count-1; $i -gt 0; $i--){
      $output[$i-1] = [pscustomobject]@{$output[$i-1] = $output[$i]}
    }
    $output[0]
  }
}

$x = $x | Convert-GCItoObject
```

Then I made my first recursive function that builds an object tree based on the paths returned by the last function. If there's a directory, it re-runs the function. So you get a progression of making objects from the bottom up.

```
function Recurse-GCIObject {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage='Items to process')]$object
  )
  $pscustomobject = [pscustomobject]@{}
  $object | Where-Object {$_} | Where-Object {$_.GetType().Name -ne 'String'} | ForEach-Object {$_.psobject.properties.name} | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    if($object.$_) {
      $pscustomobject | Add-Member @{$_ = $(Recurse-GCIObject -object $object.$_) }
    }
  }
  try {
    $pscustomobject | Add-Member -Name Contains -Value ($object | Where-Object {$_.GetType().Name -eq 'String' -and -not $pscustomobject.$_}) -MemberType NoteProperty -ErrorAction Stop
  } catch {
    Write-Verbose 'Empty'
  }
  $pscustomobject
}

$x = Recurse-GCIObject -object $x
```

At this point the object is pretty usable. I made a quick function to make the pretty tree. I didn't spend a lot of time on this, but it's readable.

```
function Out-Tree {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage='Items to process')]$InputObject, $lvl = 0
  )
  process {
    if($lvl -gt 0) { $tab = (0..$lvl | ForEach-Object {"`t"}) } else {$tab = ''}
    $InputObject | Where-Object {$_} | ForEach-Object {$_.psobject.properties.name} | ForEach-Object {
      if ($_ -ne 'Contains') {
        "$tab+-- $_ `n"
        if($InputObject.$_) {
          "$($InputObject.$_ | Out-Tree -lvl ($lvl + 1) )"
        }
      }
    }
    $InputObject.Contains | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)} | ForEach-Object { "$tab|`t|-- $_ `n" }
  }
}

$x | Out-Tree
```

There are a number of problems with this. It's very slow, the GCI output sometimes doesn't display all the correct info, and also the tree view could be a lot better. But I wanted to post this as more of a POC/exercise. I might improve it later on and invite anyone else to contribute.